# задача на комбинаторику: Сколькими способами можно выбрать из интервала от 1 до 300 три числа такие чтобы их сумма делилась на 3?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Попалась одна задача на тесте - вопервых не пойму из какой области, толи из комбинаторики, толи динамического программирования ... (но больше склоняюсь что комбинаторная)

есть числа от `1, 2, 3 ... 300`

Сколькими способами можно выбрать из них `3` числа такие чтобы их сумма делилась на 3 ?

мои мысли:

кол-во способов выбрать любые `3` числа из `300` понятное дело, что это сочетания по 3 из 300 - `C(3, 300)`

Но как теперь посчитать кол-во выборок только для тех сумма которых делится на `3` ??

ну такие числа имеют вид `3*(i + j + k)` например, а что делать дальше ??

правильно ли я выбрал направление в решении ?

Comment: Сумма 3 чисел может лежать в диапазоне от 1+2+3=6 до 298+299+300=897. Сумма 6 набирается только одним способом (1+2+3), сумма 7 - тоже одним (1+2+4), сумма 8 двумя (1+2+5 и 1+3+4)... сумма 897 - одним (298+299+300)... стандартное разложение на 3 неравных слагаемых... дальше понятно?

Comment: Всего 1485100 :) Задача - посчитать на бумажке руками или программно?

Comment: @Akina честно плохо разбираюсь в этой бухгалтерии - не вижу закономерность

Comment: @Harry на бумажке

Comment: @Harry как вы это число получили ? может хотя бы формулу напишете

Comment: Выборка делается с повторениями или без повторений? То есть можно ли `3+3+3`?

Comment: @AnT да так можно

Comment: @AnT никаких ограничений на слагаемые не налагается, критерий один - чтобы сумма делилась на 3

Comment: Да просто набросал три строчки программы :) Но - у меня выборка без повторений! С повторениями - все **гораздо** проще, можно и на бумажке...

Comment: Так все таки суммы `1+2+3` и `1+3+2` считаются за два разных варианта или за один? Был комментарий автора, утверждающий, что это - один вариант, но он был удален.

Comment: @AnT в задаче об этом ничего не говорится - можно положить что это два разных варианта

Answer (score 4):

Раз с повторениями - то все просто:
первое число - 300 способов. Второе число - еще 300. Итого - 90000. Третье число - 100 способов - тех, которые имеют нужный остаток при делении на 3. Итого - 9000000 способов.

Непосредственным перебором подтверждается :)

Вот этот код

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 300; ++i)
        for(int j = 1; j <= 300; ++j)
            for(int k = 1; k <= 300; ++k)
                if ((i+j+k)%3 == 0) ++total;

    cout << total << endl;
}
```

дает положенные 9000000

Без повторов - просто чтоб разрешить споры -

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 300; ++i)
        for(int j = i+1; j <= 300; ++j)
            for(int k = j+1; k <= 300; ++k)
                if ((i+j+k)%3 == 0) ++total;

    cout << total << endl;
}
```

дает 1485100. Можно это число *оценить* - 3 числа выбрать можно 300*299*298/6! = 455100 способами, из которых примерно треть будет нужной - 1485033 (еще раз, это - **оценка**, а не точный ответ.

P.S. Надо только уточнить - повторы одинаковых чисел считаются одинаковыми или нет? Я считал разными. Т.е. у меня фактически оценивается вероятность того, что при выборке трех чисел с возвратом в выборку будет число, делящееся на 3.

Comment: На вопрос про повторы уже был дан ответ: да, с повторами. Основной незакрытый вопрос теперь: `1+2+3` и `1+3+2` считаются как два варианта или как один?

Comment: @AnT Я как раз писал P.S. - да, я не учитывал их как  одинаковые, просто по сути рассматривая как выборку с возвратом. Согласен, это скорее всего не то, что требовалось.

Answer (score 2):

Если считать, что повторения слагаемых разрешены, но при этом варианты, получающиеся перестановкой слагаемых, не считаются разными, то составить сумму, делящуюся на 3, из трех слагаемых можно только одним из следующих способов

1. Все слагаемые дают остаток 0 при делении на 3
2. Все слагаемые дают остаток 1 при делении на 3
3. Все слагаемые дают остаток 2 при делении на 3
4. Слагаемые дают остатки 0, 1, 2 при делении на 3

Количество вариантов в каждой из первых трех групп - количество сочетаний с повторениями по 3 из 100 = (100 + 3 - 1)!/(3! * 99!) = 171700

Количество вариантов четвертой группы = 100 * 100 * 100 = 1000000

Итого: 1515100

Проверка "в лоб" дает тот же результат: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1578d2a7db5da0d9

Comment: Вот сфига бы во 2 и 3 группах по 99 чисел? во всех группах по 100...

Comment: @Akina: Верно. Спасибо за поправку.